# mod_rewrite in production environment doesn't yield the same results as locally

Tags: mod-rewrite

The goal is for all links like http://www.example.com/company/[rest-of-the-link] to go to http://www.example.com/company/#[rest-of-the-link], so basically append a hash symbol after `company/`. I have achieved it locally with the following rewrite (use NE flag for ensuring hash symbol to work correctly):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/company/[^#].*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^company/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/company/#$1 [NE,L]
```

However, when I take the very same .htaccess file and put it in the server root (file structure and database are identical locally and in production), and go to say http://www.example.com/company/members, I get a 404 error.

Moreover, for example the rule

```
RewriteRule ^company/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/ [NE,L]
```

would also cause 404 error, while for example

```
RewriteRule ^company/(.*)$ http://www.google.com/ [NE,L]
```

works alright and redirects to google.

So I was wondering, what would cause such a very strange behavior, I don't know where to start. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Links with anchors are not accessible to the server. They are limited to browsers only.